# DataContractSerializer unexpected behavior consuming SerializableAttribute

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-4.5, datacontractserializer, serializableattribute

I am trying to use the `DataContractSerializer` to serialize a simple object:

```
public class MyType {
  public string MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

I have done extensive research and discovered that [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), contrary to popular belief, the attribute `[DataContract]` is optional, and if no attribute is specified on the class then all public read/write properties and fields are serialized. And indeed, when I serialize it so - it works as expected.

Now, if I add also a `[Serializable]` attribute on the class, I get a different serialization that consists of the infamous prefix 'k__BackingField' (since my property is an auto property).

My questions:

1. Can anyone explain *why* the DataContractSerializer would behave differently with and without the [Serializable] attribute? Not the technical explanation (which is probably something like "in this case the base class of XmlObjectSerializer is taking over"), but the design reason. I cannot see how this different serialization is useful in any way. If anything - it breaks backward compatibility. Does it make sense to suggest a change to Microsoft?
2. If I don't want to go over our whole gigantic data model and decorate everything with [DataContract] and [DataMember] - is there a more generic way to tell the DataContractSerializer, or the WCF infrastructure (via a service contract attribute or such), to serialize also classes marked [Serializable] in its default (read: undecorated) behavior? Unfortunately, the attribute [XmlSerializerFormat] is not an option for me, I need to stick with the DataContractSerializer for WCF.

Answer (score -1):

**For your first question:** The `[Serializable]` attribute is intended for .NET Remoting transportation which comes with its legacy compatibility serialization. So it isn't encouraged to apply this attribute when you're using WCF. You can read more about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6exf3h2k.aspx).

**Your second question**, is not easy to answer without more details. An easy workaround would be to apply the `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot()]` attribute to your data model class. This attribute is not intended for webservices though, but it does provide the clean SOAP messages that also ignore private properties. Interoperability might be a concern, I have not tested this.

A better workaround is really to use `[DataContract]`. Which allows you fine control over the data that you send over the wire. Sending huge data models over services are a code smell more than anything in my opinion. I would try and refactor these into smaller classes where possible.

Comment: -1 I'm afraid this (A) does not answer either my questions, (B) states a solution I specifically ask about avoiding and (C) has some incorrect statemets.
#1: [Serializable] is not just for .NET Remoting, but is necessary for any binary serialization, which my DM needs since it is serialized via .NET session mechanism.
#2: XmlRoot has no effect on DataContractSerializer, only on XmlSerializer, and as I mentioned I must stick with the former.